# Hadoop NameNode Web Interface

Tags: java, ubuntu, web, hadoop, ssh

I have 3 remote computers (servers):

- computer 1 has internal IP: **10.1.7.245**
- computer 2 has internal IP: 10.1.7.246
- computer 3 has internal IP: 10.1.7.247

(The 3 computers above are in the same network, these 3 computers are all using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Operating System)

(My personal laptop is in another different network, my laptop also uses Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Operating System)

I use **my personal laptop** to connect to the 3 remote computers using SSH protocol and using user *root* : (Below **ABC** is a name)

- computer 1: `ssh root@ABC.University.edu.vn -p 12001`
- computer 2: `ssh root@ABC.University.edu.vn -p 12002`
- computer 3: `ssh root@ABC.University.edu.vn -p 12003`

I have successfully set up a Hadoop Cluster which contains 3 above computer:

- computer 1 is the Hadoop Master
- computer 2 is the Hadoop Slave 1
- computer 3 is the Hadoop Slave 2

======================================================

I starts HDFS of the Hadoop Cluster by using the below command on Computer 1: `start-dfs.sh`

Everything is successful:

- computer 1 (the Master) is running the NameNode
- computer 2 (the Slave 1) is running the DataNode
- computer 3 (the Slave 2) is running the DataNode

I know that the the **Web Interface** for the NameNode is running on **Computer 1**, on IP **0.0.0.0** and on port **9870** . Therefore, if I open the web browser on computer 1 (or on computer 2, or on computer 3), I will enter the **10.1.7.245:9870** on the URL bar (address bar) of the web browser to see the Web Interface of the NameNode.

======================================================

Now, I am using the web browser of **my personal laptop**.

**How could I access to the Web Interface of the NameNode ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer for my problem.

In the SSH session connects to Computer 1, I will specify a port **A** ( **A** is a port number, in my case, I prefer to choose port number **18080** ) on my personal laptop **localhost** , this port **A** will be forwarded to the **given host** and **port** on the **remote side** . Here, the **given host** on the **remote side** will be **0.0.0.0** and the **port** on the **remote side** will be **9870**. So the SSH command to start the SSH connection session to Computer 1 is presented below:

`ssh -L 18080:0.0.0.0:9870 root@ABC.University.edu.vn -p 12001`

And finally, **on the web browser of my personal laptop**, I enter the address **localhost:18080** in the URL bar of the web browser to **access the Web Interface of the Hadoop NameNode**

The above is the method that solves the problem in my circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you expose port 9870, your personal laptop on another network will not be able to access the web interface.

You can check to see if it is exposed by trying :9870 to see if it is exposed. IP-address here has to be the global IP-address, not the local (10.* ) address.

To get the NameNode's IP address, ssh into the NameNode server, and type ifconfig (sudo apt install ifconfig if not already installed - I'm assuming Ubuntu/Linux here). ifconfig should give you a global IP address (not the 255.* - that is a mask).

Comment: I really appreciate Mr @Beenish , I am checking to see if the port is exposed. By the way, I am still a junior Stack Overflow user, could you tell me things to avoid to ask in a Stack Overflow question in order to keep the question from being voted down ?

Comment: I've only recently started to get involved in Stack Overflow myself. The tour explains what makes a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/tour